# Manage Waypoints on Rviz

Tags: navigation, rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have a ground-robot (2D) and I want to manage (insert,delete and move) a simple set of waypoints in rviz, that will be used to define the path! (i will subscribe the map of gmapping)

What solution there is available for this? I have see the interactive markers, i don't need a complex solution like this!

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36999/manage-waypoints-on-rviz/) by [Filipe Santos](https://answers.ros.org/users/907/filipe-santos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 346 on 2012-06-21

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I generally use disk-shaped markers for way-points, like this:

```
def mark_way_points(self, color):
    """Create slightly transparent disks for way-points.

    :param color: disk RGBA value
    """
    index = 0
    for wp in self.map_points:
        marker = Marker(header = self.map.header,
                        ns = "waypoints_osm",
                        id = index,
                        type = Marker.CYLINDER,
                        action = Marker.ADD,
                        scale = Vector3(x=2., y=2., z=0.2),
                        color = color,
                        lifetime = self.marker_life)
        index += 1
        # use easting and northing coordinates (ignoring altitude)
        marker.pose.position = wp.toPointXY()
        marker.pose.orientation = Quaternion(x=0., y=0., z=0., w=1.)
        self.msg.markers.append(marker)
```

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have a look at the parsec repository at http://parsec.googlecode.com. In particular the packages `interactive_waypoint_markers` and `navigation_waypoints_server` should be interesting for you. In the repository, you can also find example launch files, e.g. [here](https://code.google.com/p/parsec/source/browse/interactive_waypoint_markers/launch/interactive_waypoint_markers.launch).

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-06-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1